# Restart loop in a parallel array

Tags: c++, loops

For my assignment, I cannot allow a user to enter a negative value for `rainfall` in the array. I'm suppose to restart the loop over again as if they didn't enter anything to start off with and have them try again.

When I try it, I enter a negative value the first time, it restarts it for January, but after that I can enter more negatives and it just keeps asking me to keep entering for the rest of the months. I want it to keep restarting if I keep giving it negative numbers, until I start entering positive numbers. Then, that's when I display the total and average.

```
{
    const int SIZE = 12;
    string months[SIZE] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };

    string Month[SIZE];
    double Rainfall[SIZE];
    int counter;

    double totalRainfall = 0.0;

    double averageRainfall = 0.0;

    for (counter = 0; counter < SIZE; counter++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the total rainfall for " << months[counter] << ": ";
        cin >> Rainfall[counter];

        if (Rainfall[counter] < 0.0)
        {
            cout << "Sorry, can't be a negative!" << endl;
            do
            {
                for (counter = 0; counter < SIZE; counter++)
                {
                    cout << "Enter the total rainfall for " << months[counter] << ": ";
                    cin >> Rainfall[counter];
                }
            } while (Rainfall[counter] < 0.0);
        }

        averageRainfall = totalRainfall / SIZE;
        cout << "Total rainfall for the whole year was: " << totalRainfall << setprecision(3) << endl;
        cout << "The average inches of rainfall was: " << averageRainfall << setprecision(3) << endl;

        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: restart back to January or the current month they are inputting values for?

Comment: I would really like it if it would restart back to January.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic working example to what you are trying to accomplish. Rather than adding and then checking, I checked first before I add the value into the array. I created a simple function to make sure that the input is a valid number. If its not, simply reset the counter back to 0 and the for loop will start from the beginning.

Edit: add a try and catch block to make sure input is a proper double

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool is_valid_num(std::string str){

    //check if its a number
    for(char c : str){
        if((c < 48 || c > 57 ) && c != 46) return false;
    }

    //if you want it to also not be equal to 0
    // if(std::stoi(str) < 0) return false;

    return true;
}

int main() {

    const int SIZE = 12;
    std::string months[] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
                        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };


    std::string temp_input;
    double rainfall[12]; 
    double total_rainfall = 0.0;

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){

        std::cout << "enter rainfall for " << months[i] << ": ";
        std::cin >> temp_input;

        //restart back to january
        if(!(is_valid_num(temp_input))) i = -1;

        rainfall[i] = std::stod(temp_input);
        total_rainfall += std::stod(temp_input);

    }

    std::cout << "avg rainfall: " << total_rainfall / 12.0 << "\n";
    std::cout << "total rainfall " << total_rainfall << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well that's your while loop where you are stuck, when second time you put negative values you are already in while loop so it wont print sorry.... rather it will restart while loop from counter = 0,
rather do this

```
if (Rainfall[counter] < 0.0)
    {
        cout << "Sorry, can't be a negative!" << endl;
        counter--;// either put zero if you want to restart whole loop else decrement
        continue;
    }
```